# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How to send an e-mail with external link in workflow step

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to send an e-mail with an external link using microsoft crm online 2011 workflow to gmail or hotmail, but the link don't work.
I tried to use a "HyperLink" and an url at body of e-mail, but any of them worked.
When i used a HyperLink, no one link was added in "href" property of "a" .
And, when i used a normal text, no link was added.
Someone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: so you are saying that the links are broken? rollup version?

Comment: Did you try putting html in the workflow email? e.g. <a href="your_url.com">link</a>

Comment: Yes, i tried. But it was sent as text with "<a>". :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's might be limitation of Microsoft Exchange server who is working behind the MS CRM Online. It looks like security limitation, anti-fishing protection, not allowing people to send spam on behalf of Microsoft CRM instance.

Comment: Yes, can be. Thanks for reply, but i dont need to find solution to this anymore.